# Combinatorics permutations of $n$ elements of which $k$ are optional and $n - k$ are mandatory

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I am trying to formulate a formula for the following combinatorics problem:

Let's say I have $2$ letters $I$ and $L$ . $I$ is mandatory, meaning that it should appear in each permutation, $L$ is not. So i can have the following permutations:

$$|(I\text{ }L), (L\text{ }I), (I)| = \text{3 
permutations}$$

For $3$ letters $I, L, M$ so that $I$ is mandatory and the other $2$ are optional, I have:

$$
|(\text{I L M}), (\text{I M L}), (\text{L I M}), \\
(\text{L M I}), (\text{M I L}), (\text{M L I}), \\
(\text{I L}), (\text{I M}), (\text{L I}), \\
(M I), (I)| = \text{11 permutations}
$$

For $n = 4$ letters one of which is a mandatory letter $I$ which should be in each permutation, I have:

$$4! + (4 - 1)(3!) + (4 - 1)(2!) + 1 = \text{49 permutations}$$

So I ended up writing the following formula for any $n \geq 3$ when one letter of the $n$ letters (assuming $I$) is mandatory (each letter is different from the other):

$$n! + \left [ (n - 1) \cdot \sum_{i = 2}^{n - 1} i! \right ] + 1$$

Now, how can I generalise this formula when the number of mandatory letters of $n$ increases from $1$ to $k$ ?

Comment: In your last formula,  there should be no $ k $, and you can incorporate the outsiders by having  $i $ start at $1 $ and go to $ n $.

Comment: I am sorry, please check my edit

Comment: It does look better,  but I think it is wrong - if I understand the problem correctly.  Don't you agree with the general formula that I gave below?

Comment: I am trying to understand your formula, I have to revise combinatorics a little bit. Why do you think that the formula I wrote for $n \geq 3$ and $k = 1$ is wrong?

Comment: Just write down $ n=5 $ explicitly, you will see that your formula fails at the middle term. Your factor $ n-1 $ is just a special case of a binomial coefficient.

Comment: You are right, for $n = 5$ when I compute the permutations against a set of $3$ letters one of which mandatory, I get more than $(n - 1) \cdot 3! = 4 \cdot 3!$ permutations.

Comment: Sure enough, the right coefficient is not 5-1, but 5-1 choose 2.

Answer (score 2):

You have $ n-k \choose i $ ways to choose which optional letters you take,  once you have decided to take $i$ of them.

Then $(k+i)! $ ways to order the letters that you have.

Therefore the answer is $$\sum_{i=0}^{n-k}{n-k \choose i}(k+i)! $$

Comment: Could you please provide a walkthrough on how to elaborate the formula you wrote?

Comment: You have to add the number of words containing $i$ optionals, over all $ i $.  For fixed $ i $ you have $2 $ choices to make,  which $ i $ letters you take and what is the order of your $ k+i $ letters in the end. The number of options for choice $2 $ is independent of the first choice made, therefore you multiply (fundamental principle of counting).